# Java OutputStream read() works, read(buffer) creates error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an encrypted Zip file using the library at https://bitbucket.org/matulic/ziputils/overview. As described at http://blog.alutam.com/2012/03/31/new-library-for-reading-and-writing-zip-files-in-java, I used `read()` to read each byte and it works without any mistakes. However when I tried to use a buffer (which I believe is more efficient), the file I get has an error. The code I used is below:

```
FileInputStream src = new FileInputStream("ZIP_FILE_PATH");
ZipEncryptOutputStream dest = new ZipEncryptOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ENCRYPTED_FILE_PATH"), "password");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while ((count = src.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    dest.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
dest.close();
src.close();
```

When I unzip the file with WinRAR, a CRC error is shown (When I use `read()`, this doesn't happen). An interesting thing to note is that in the failed file, in file properties the **file size** of the encrypted file is less than the original file but the **size on disk** property is the same. What might be wrong here?

Comment: is the result the same when you replace `dest.write(buffer, 0, count);` with a loop that writes each byte via `ZipEncryptOutputStream.write(byte)`? if yes: then `ZipEncryptOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int)` is to blame, if no then something you're not showing.

Comment: Concur. Likely cause is the library itself.

Comment: I mentioned in the question itself, there is no error when I use `write(byte)`. So I think you're right, it might be a problem with the library's implementation.